# Installed minimal CentOS 6.4 in VirtualBox but have no internet?

Tags: virtualbox, centos-6

I just started using the VirtualBox, but I don't seem to have any internet on the CentOS when I type `yum update`. Is there a solution to my problem? (it could possibly be a problem with misconfigured VirtualBox)

Here is an output of `ifconfig`.

[image]

Comment: What is the output of your ifconfig?

Comment: http://puu.sh/3mHVp.jpg

Comment: Yeah, you have no eth0 - just the loop back. I think I have the answer for you.

Comment: I have just installed it, it's 100% clean. Maybe I need to configure my VirtualBox?

Comment: @user0000001 - Update your question with the screenshot and I will upvote this question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Looks like your eth0 is not set up. Here is what I did to fix mine on CentOS 6.4.

```
sudo su -

cat /etc/sysconfig/network |grep -i network
```

This should return: *NETWORKING=yes* - If it does not, then change it to yes.

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

This should look like:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
HWADDR="08:00:27:07:9e:57"
NM_CONTROLLED="YES"
ONBOOT="NO"
```

There are a few options that we want to change here, NM_CONTROLLED needs to be NO, ONBOOT needs to be YES, and finally add this code at the bottom:

```
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
```

This will allow you to grab an IP from your DHCP and essentially enable IPV4.

Now the whole file should look like this:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
HWADDR="08:00:27:07:9e:57"
NM_CONTROLLED="NO"
ONBOOT="YES"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
```

Save and close. Now, lets restart the network service to reload with these settings:

```
[root@Development ~]# service network restart
Shutting down interface eth0:                              [  OK  ]
Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:
Determining IP information for eth0... done.
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

Notice the ‘eth0′ – awesome! Now lets check to see if we got an IPV4 from our DHCP:

```
ifconfig
```

You should now see 'eth0'.

Comment: About to try this.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Yes sir, it works like a charm.

Comment: I am getting an error http://i.imgur.com/f4Eai6b.png

Comment: To me it looks like your virtual box VM is in a bridged mode ( attached to your hosts NIC ) and not getting it's own IP from your DHCP server. ( your router )  You tried to ping a 192.168.X.X address from a different subnet 10.X.X.X. Try to change your VMs NIC settings in virtualbox to NAT or independent.

Comment: This worked wonders for me when setting up CentOS in VirtualBox.

Comment: For anyone doing this on CentOS 7, you you won't have an eth0. It will be called enp0s3 instead.

Answer (score 5):

You have no networking configured. you should have enabled it during install (its not obvious, I missed it too during my first minimal-install).
Try:

```
dhclient eth0 # gets you DHCP on en0
```

This will get you started. Then try:

```
yum install system-config-network-tui
```

Which will give you a curses based network config program where you can set things permanently.

Comment: Awesome, it works. Thanks. Will I have to type the `dhclient eth0` each time I reboot my virtual machine?

Comment: Btw, getting an error http://puu.sh/3mIhT.png

Comment: No, use the network tool that you just installed with yum to enable DHCP on boot.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, but all I needed to do was edit the network-script to yes for onboot and restart the network.

Edit the network-script

```
 vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3

 bla bla=bla
 ...
 onboot=yes
```

Restart network

```
 systemctl restart network
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're installing CentOS, on the networking page, there is a button at the bottom left that allows you to configure the network settings. Click edit next to eth0 and find the checkbox to set the network to connect automatically.